# In Firestore, how do I change for all documents of a collection of which a certain field has a certain value, that field in a certain value?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to change the value of a certain field of all documents in a Cloud Firestore collection to a certain value if that field is equal to a certain value. How do I do that?

Comment: You do it by updating each document, one at a time. If you have 10 documents or 1,000, you have to update them one by one. You can _start_ with a single request to get all to-be-updated documents, but then after that it's one operation per document.

Comment: Also, this isn't due to anything about Java, but instead how Firestore works. If you switched from Java to some other language, the situation would be the same – update one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Doug's answer, if you want to update all documents in a collection where a field contains a certain value, then please use the following lines of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = db.collection("collName").whereEqualTo("fieldName", "fieldValue");
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                document.getReference().update("fieldToUpdate", "value");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey Jonathan. Have you tried the code in my answer, does it work?

Answer (score 1):

1. Query with a filter that matches all of the documents you want to chage.
2. Iterate the results of that query.
3. Update each document with the new field value it should contain.